# How can I clear the central cache for `npx`?

Tags: npx

Let's say you're running this command:

```sh
npx gulp
```

`npx` will search for `gulp` within `node_modules/.bin`, and if it doesn't find it there, it will use a central cache. If it is missing, `npx` will install it.

How do I clear the central cache to force `npx` to reinstall `gulp` in this case?

Comment: `npx gulp@latest`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe unfortunately that didn't refresh the cache for `npx gulp`. After a couple of days I just had to clear the cache manually because it wasn't getting updated.

Answer (score 82):

On macOS (and likely Linux) it's `~/.npm/_npx`, you can drop it with:

```sh
rm -rf ~/.npm/_npx
```

On Windows it should be `%LocalAppData%/npm-cache/_npx`

---

Either way, you can find npm’s cache by running `npm config get cache` and then finding an npx folder in there.

Comment: Why is NPX keeping around outdated versions of packages that you need to explicitly purge? Doesn't seem right

Comment: @ChrisM yeah it seems like `npx` should be an extension of `npm` yet it doesn't seem to have similar tooling to handle caching unfortunately. I would imagine there must be a ticket open around this, but wasn't finding anything off hand here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues There also doesn't seem to be many options in the official documentation either: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npx

Comment: If you want to know the exact directory it's running from rather than blindly clearing all of the cache you can run: `npx -p gulp which gulp` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67030685/349659

Comment: Even if I remove it it will still install the old one, so it's best to just tag the version with `@latest` I guess :\

Comment: Can confirm this works in Linux.

@CTS_AE This behavior has been reported in a couple of different bugs, and both times, NPM has said it is intended behavior: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2329, https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4108

Answer (score 39):

I needed to do this, due to an error in create-react-app saying 'We no longer support global installation of Create React App.' despite there being no global install. It was stuck in the npx cache, and I removed it like this

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Comment: I also ran into this same issue. I was able to get around it by running `npx create-react-app@latest`. Upon inspecting the `~/.npm/_npx` I was able to see that both still exist there though. To find them I opened up the directory in VSCode via `code ~/.npm/_npx` and ran a search for `create-react-app` with `files to include` set to `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll provide a very different answer here, though hopefully it may still be useful.

If I install a package named `prettier`, then the files npx caches for that package will be saved in `~/.npm/_npx/b388654678d519d9`, where `b388654678d519d9` is the first 16 characters of the SHA512 hash:

```
$ echo -n prettier | sha512sum | cut -c-16
b388654678d519d9
```

You can see this construction happen in the [libnpmexec source code](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/workspaces/libnpmexec/lib/index.js#L210). Notably, there is nothing about the package version or the directory or package.json from which it was installed, so I'm not sure how npx is keeping straight which version to cache there.