# Where does NPX store binaries after installation?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

If I'm using `npx` to run a binary as a one-off, it'll output the following:

```
npx my-module 

/// npx: installed 1 in 1.34s
/// Hello, from my module!
```

Where are these binaries stored by default? Does `npx` save the binaries after execution, a-la `npm` or does it just run them and then remove the files?

It's my understanding that `npx` will first look in the local `node_modules/.bin` diectory and then the `/usr/local/bin` directory, before it downloads the module. But I've checked both of those locations and don't see the new module...

Comment: usr/local/bin not .bin

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not seeing any of the npx binaries in there. Everything is running fine. Just curious where the files are installed on my system

Comment: Could be in ~/.cache or ~/.local?

Comment: Try this: `npx SOME_PACKAGE_WITH_BINARY_THAT_ISNT_INSTALLED_LOCALLY && find / -type f -name 'SOME_PACKAGE_WITH_BINARY_THAT_ISNT_INSTALLED_LOCALLYS_BINARY'`.

Comment: > Try this: npx SOME_PACKAGE_WITH_BINARY_THAT_ISNT_INSTALLED_LOCALLY && find / -type f -name 'SOME_PACKAGE_WITH_BINARY_THAT_ISNT_INSTALLED_LOCALLYS_BINARY'

Do this instead: `npx -p SOME_PACKAGE which SOME_PACKAGE` or `npx -p SOME_PACKAGE command -v SOME_PACKAGE`. That will be much faster than using `find` to search through the entire filesystem for the executable.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`npm` version 7 will cache the packages in a `_npx` directory. It has a cache layout that apparently involves a hash. For example, for me `npx shellcheck` installs the executable in `~/.npm/_npx/cca5ebdff9ce100b/node_modules/.bin/shellcheck`. (Note the `cca5ebdff9ce100b`.) However, I very much doubt that the algorithm can be relied upon to be consistent across versions of `npx`.

The whole point of `npx` is that you can run the packages without installing them somewhere permanent. So I wouldn't use that cache location for anything. I wouldn't be surprised if cache entries were cleared from time to time. I don't know what algorithm, if any, `npx` uses for time-based cache invalidation.

To get the location from which `npx` runs the package, you can use `-p` to tell it to install a package and then use `which <executable>` or `command -v <executable>` to get the path. So, for example, what I did above to get the location of the `shellcheck` executable was to run `npx -p shellcheck which shellcheck` or `npx -p shellcheck command -v shellcheck`. Those commands assume a Linux or other UNIX-like operating system. I'm not sure what the equivalent for Windows would be.

```
$ npx -p shellcheck command -v shellcheck
Need to install the following packages:
  shellcheck
Ok to proceed? (y) 
/Users/trott/.npm/_npx/cca5ebdff9ce100b/node_modules/.bin/shellcheck
$
```

Answer (score 5):

In Windows, this would be:
`C:\Users\{YourUserName}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\`

or the bash shell equivalent of:
`~/Local Settings/npm-cache/_npx/` etc.