# Syntax error running npx cdk on a github runner

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I'm having the darndest time figuring out what is going wrong when I try to run CDK via `npx` on my runner.

If I execute `npx cdk --version` on the runner, I get this error:

```
/home/github-actions/.npm/_npx/2abb9f1d4e0b8716/node_modules/.bin/cdk: 1: import: not found
/home/github-actions/.npm/_npx/2abb9f1d4e0b8716/node_modules/.bin/cdk: 2: import: not found
/home/github-actions/.npm/_npx/2abb9f1d4e0b8716/node_modules/.bin/cdk: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

How do I figure out what is wrong with the CDK installation?

Shooting in the dark, I tried:

```
$ npm install which
$ npx which cdk
/usr/local/bin/actions-runner/_work/jundai-deleteme-0913-01/jundai-deleteme-0913-01/.infra/node_modules/.bin/cdk
```

If I run *that* CDK, it happily spits out a version:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/actions-runner/_work/jundai-deleteme-0913-01/jundai-deleteme-0913-01/.infra/node_modules/.bin/cdk --version
2.93.0 (build 724bd01)
```

but for some reason `npx cdk` is linking to a totally different path? What is causing it to do that and how do I see how it resolving the path to the binary? (and why might it be failing?)

my PATH is not very interesting and there is no cdk in it:

```
/usr/local/bin/actions-runner/_work/_tool/node/18.17.1/x64/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

EDIT: reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67028703/where-does-npx-store-binaries-after-installation) and a few other things, it seems like npx "installs" the binary into a temporary location in the home folder, so that part is acting as it should. But it's totally unclear *why* the installed cdk is failing, how I'm supposed to troubleshoot it, and I still don't understand why there's another version of the binary in the local project `node_modules/.bin`, why *that* one works, and why npx isn't using it.