# npx create-react-app prompting to globally uninstall non-existent create-react-app package?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarnpkg, npx

I am having problems with npx create-react-app involving global installs. My confusion arises because as far as I'm aware the create-react-app package is not installed on my machine.

Some Details:

I start a react project (with typescript template) as I have previously and recently done on this same machine a number of times:

`npx create-react-app --template typescript .`

I get this prompt from the terminal

`Need to install the following packages: create-react-app Ok to proceed? (y)`

I press y to confirm it's okay to proceed. (If I press n, the process terminates with the following error: `npm ERR! canceled`.) The terminal then displays the following message

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

I run both suggested commands to uninstall create-react-app globally.
npm goes smoothly:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 179ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

the global yarn uninstall results with the following message:

```
remove create-react-app
yarn global v1.22.17
warning package.json: No license field
[1/2]   Removing module create-react-app...
error This module isn't specified in a package.json file.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
```

Finally I try to find if create-react-app exists on my machine with
`which create-react-app`
which results in
`create-react-app not found`.

I'm not sure how else to address this issue.

**Edit: Solution provided by Deepthi and Sators. I had to clear the npx cache which had stored an older version of create-react-app by using command:**

`npx clear-npx-cache`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating new React app ("You are running \`create-react-app\` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-app-you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-w)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try to locate the installed version by running:

```
npm ls -g create-react-app
```

You may also want to consider reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66019858/659188) for removing/clearing the npx cache by using:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Finally, another option is to ensure you are using the latest version of create-react-app by running:

```
npx create-react-app@latest --template typescript .
```

Comment: Clearing the npx cache did the trick for me. I'm in happy hacking territory again, much appreciated!!!

Comment: Hello, i'm having a similar issue, but with `yarn create react-app` i clean all my caches, and delete all the global installations, but the issue persists. Any idea why this could be happening? - btw, i cannot use v5.0.0 because my server is on Node 12

Comment: You could try `yarn create react-app@latest`

Answer (score 102):

For something like this encountered:
" You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)."

Solution was :

```
>  npx clear-npx-cache
```

Then do:

```
> npx create-react-app your-app
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried everything from clearing npm cache to uninstalling and reinstalling node, finally this solution fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks! that command fixed my issue.

Comment: this does works! please tick this answer

Comment: I am running into stuck after running `npx clear-npx-cache` with node v14.16.0 and npm 6.14.11 on Windows 10

Comment: still working with npm 8.11.0 and node v16.15.1 ! Thank you !

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is that the npx create-react-app is trying to install packages from an older version (4.0.3) while the latest version is (5.0.0).

**You can simply clear the npx cache by using the following command:**

`npx clear-npx-cache`

and then try to create a react app again using

`npx create-react-app Your_project_name`

**Or**

**You can use npx with @latest to guarantee that you are running create-react-app along with the latest version:**

`npx create-react-app@latest Your_project_name`

**Or**

**you can install the latest react app modules locally in the working directory by using:**

`npm install create-react-app@latest`

(This will create react modules in addition to package.json and package-lock.json in the working directory which will be depended on when installing the react app, so you can delete them after finishing the next step)

and then:

`npx create-react-app Your_project_name`

Comment: Thanks @sanad-khamash. `npx create-react-app@latest` worked for me to ensure that I am running `create-react-app` latest version.

Comment: @Shraddha You're more than welcome sir.

Comment: npx create-react-app@latest Your_project_name worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Apparently there is a problem with that version, I just have the same issue, but with the command

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

It did the trick, then I've just run the

```
npx create-react-app proyect-name
```

And it works!

I think this is the same answer as above, but well, there you go.

Answer (score 4):

Run --->   npx clear-npx-cache

```
 ----> npx create-react-app your-app
```

Comment: Please remove the ----> that is unnecessary and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

**Why?**

You already tried to create a react project using create-react-app before.

So there is an old version of create-react-app in the npx cache.
`/user/.npm/_npx`

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app` won't work for this case.

If you run `npx clear-npx-cache` it will remove all the caches in the directory `/user/.npm/_npx`

Now you can create react app using

```
npx create-react-app my_app
```

Comment: This works, everyone else that answered below didn't read the OP question. They already tried all of those suggestions.

Comment: @Batman thanks for your comment, seems like people don't want to know the reason, but only the solution.

Comment: removing .npm/_cacache/ did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

Try running:
`npm update`

Then run: `npx create-react-app my_app`

or you can also try with '@latest': `npx create-react-app@latest my_app`

Answer (score 0):

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Yes it appears as is as it is above.

Run some of these two options:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

OR

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

Finally try again with npx command create-react-app

In my case, I use the one from `npm unistall`, finally run the command `npx create-react-app` again there if I started to create React project.

Answer (score 0):

if you've tried everything above and no success.

Run:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Then:

```
npx create-react-app <app
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above method worked then follow:

1. `npm i create-react-app@latest_version`

   For example : npm i create-react-app@5.0.1
2. `npx create-react-app app_name`

   For example : npx create-react-app@5.0.1 .

Answer (score 0):

After trying all above proposed solutions and failing, here is the solution that worked for me:

1. Navigate to `~/.npm/_npx` and ls
2. You will see a directory **similar** to this: `c67e74de0542c87c/`
3. cd to it
4. Open package.json and overwrite:
   {
   "dependencies": {
   "create-react-app": "^4.0.3"
   }
   }
   **with**
   {
   "dependencies": {
   "create-react-app": "^5.0.1"
   }
   }
5. Now you can run `npx create-react-app <app-name>`

Hopefully this will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npx create-react-app@latest app_name
```

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue and it was happening because I was using `nvm` to manage node versions and I was running an older node version (12.14.1) for a client project. Using node v14.x.x solved the issue for me.