# A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app (NPM issue)

Tags: reactjs, macos, npm

I know this is an old issue but it showed up after upgrading my npm,

> A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an
> outdated version of create-react-app. Please note that global installs
> of create-react-app are no longer supported. You can fix this by
> running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove
> create-react-app before using create-react-app again.

I tried to fix it with:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
yarn global uninstall create-react-app
npx create-react-app [name of folder]
```

It did not work

The next step, clean node cache

same issue

the last step I removed npm and node from my system and install it again

same issue.

There are some clues here but it does not work for me

source: [Template not provided using create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app)

I just want to repair this, not use flags command options.

Any recommendations are welcome anyway.

Comment: I had the same issue, the solution was: npx clear-npx-cache                              see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352503/npx-create-react-app-prompting-to-globally-uninstall-non-existent-create-react-a/70358238#70358238

Answer (score 0):

I removed all node and npm folders from

```
/usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

even a ".npm" and ".node" hidden files that were in my user home folder, and I realize my IDE WebStorm had one also, so I removed my IDE as well, I rebooted the machine just in case as windows computer, and install Node and npm again "stable version" and then the IDE, it works at the moment.

source: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x?rq=1)