# Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

Tags: reactjs

PS E:\New folder> npx create-react-app my-app
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: i'm not able to create a react appp

Comment: I had the same problem recently. What I did to break this cycle was to `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then install it (the latest version) globally again: `npm install -g create-react-app`. It works fine from global installation  despite what it says.

Answer (score 27):

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

and then

```
 npx create-react-app your-app
```

It works for me

from:[npx create-react-app prompting to globally uninstall non-existent create-react-app package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352503/npx-create-react-app-prompting-to-globally-uninstall-non-existent-create-react-a)

Comment: Worked in my case. Interesting fact: since the command deletes the cache it will also delete its own executable.

Answer (score 6):

Step-1 `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Step-2 `npm install -g create-react-app`

It works for me if it still not works for you try
`npx clear-npx-cache` after global uninstallation.

Comment: thanks, the command `npx clear-npx-cache` worked

Answer (score 0):

When I run npx clear-npx-cache i get:

TypeError: fs_1.rmSync is not a function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).