# Why npm uninstall -g create-react-app fails?

Tags: reactjs, uninstallation, npx

I'm working on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

If I run `npx create-react-app myapp` the system responds with an error:

```
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) 

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

then, when I run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` the the uninstall do nothing:

```
xxx@xxx:/prj$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 307ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

So, I cannot create a new react application using `npx`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963796/create-react-app-is-not-working-since-version-4-0-1

Comment: You’ll need to have Node >= 14 on your local development machine. Do you have it?. $ node --version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app is not working since version 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963796/create-react-app-is-not-working-since-version-4-0-1)

Comment: The running answer I found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352503/npx-create-react-app-prompting-to-globally-uninstall-non-existent-create-react-a is
`npx clear-npx-cache`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this issue and this worked for me, after `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` :

---

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm cache verify`
3. `npx clear-npx-cache` to clear your npx cache.
4. `npx create-react-app your-app` or `npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm`