# I am getting this error while installing create-react-app package even after updating the package

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
npx create-react-app my-app
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y)

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

Answer (score 1):

as it says in the error you need to remove the global installation of create-react-app, so run these two commands based on if you are using npm or yarn:

```
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
```

after it's done open up the terminal in your directory again and use the npx command. it should do the trick.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Same error after removing react global installation

Comment: I have reinstalled node JS but getting same error

Comment: you don't need to remove react or node. just remove create-react-app. run the two commands I mentioned & then open another terminal and run npx command again.

Comment: done but error is same

Comment: Kindly help me with this error i am unable to complete my project

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352503/npx-create-react-app-prompting-to-globally-uninstall-non-existent-create-react-a) try deleting the npx cache

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```