# Error while creating new React app ("You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)")

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, create-react-app, npx

I am getting this create React app error again and again even after doing the uninstall part.

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

> up to date, audited 1 package in 570ms
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

`npx create-react-app test-app`

> Need to install the following packages:   create-react-app Ok to
> proceed? (y) y
>
> You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest
> release (5.0.0).
>
> We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
>
> Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
>
> - npm uninstall -g create-react-app
> - yarn global remove create-react-app
>
> The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
> https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

```
C:\>npm --version
8.3.0
C:\>node --version
v16.13.0
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Try running `npx clear-npx-cache` to clear your npx cache and then running the `npx create-react-app your-app` command.

Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66019858/3778283) on clearing the cache.

Additionally, it might be worth trying to force the latest version with:

`npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm`

Comment: your second command work but I don't get that, why this error I got ?

Comment: In my case after running 'npx create-react-app' there was a notice about new major version of npm in there terminal. I use 'npm install -g npm@x.x.x' (x need to be replaced with the shown version in the notice ). after that I run 'npx create-react-app' it worked.

Answer (score 21):

I have resolved with the following steps:

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npx clear-npx-cache`
3. `npx create-react-app myapp`

Answer (score 12):

#### Solution 1: Force to the latest version

Just try to run the create command with *force* to the latest version. Just like this:

```
npx create-react-app@latest_version my-app --use-npm
```

And the *latest* version is **5.0.0** so *just try* this command:

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app
```

Now, your error must be solved.

#### Solution 2: Clear the cache

You just need to clear your cache and then you can create a new React project. First of all, clear the cache by running this command:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

If it does not work, use this and try again: Delete everything from this path.

```
C:\Users\Your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

On macOS (and likely Linux), it’s ~/.npm/_npx. You can drop it with:

```
rm -rf ~/.npm/_npx
```

Or try the command `npm cache clean --force` using administrator mode in your terminal. Now, just rerun your create command.

```
npx create-react-app your-app
```

#### Solution 3: Run this command

Just run this command one by one.

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm cache verify`
4. `npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: For me this worked with `create-react-app@latest`, didn't work with `create-react-app@latest_version`

Answer (score 4):

You will have to clear the npx cache to make it work.

You can locate the location of the folder where create-react-app is installed using `npm ls -g create-react-app`.

Also, to clear the cache, refer to this answer in *[How can I clear the central cache for `npx`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510325/how-can-i-clear-the-central-cache-for-npx/66019858#66019858)*

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sawan, yes clearing the cache did resolve my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by running

```
$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

then

```
$ npx clear-npx-cache
```

then

```
$ npm install -g create-react-app@5.0.0
```

and then finally it was able to use:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply doing `npx create-react-app@latest my-app-name` worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

(npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app) worked like a charm and its also much faster now then old react js

Answer (score 2):

I followed the above suggestions but it didn't solve my problem.
Below steeps solved my problem

1- Learn npm cache folder path:
**npm cache verify**
This gives you npm cache folder path:
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache_cacache)

2- Go to"..\npm-cache" folder and delete everything

3- Cerate your project:
**npx create-react-app my-app**

Answer (score 2):

I tried both and they all works fine. You can try any of them.

**npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app**
or
**npx clear-npx-cache**

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue and I fixed it by running the following commands:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
npm cache verify
```

Go to"..\npm-cache" folder that you get its path from previous command and delete everything

```
npm install -g npm@8.3.0
npx create-react-app your_app_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and no matter what I tried (i.e. clearing cache, uninstalling -g create-react-app, etc..) nothing worked.

I had to use:

```
$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

**and**

```
$ npm uninstall create-react-app
```

and then I was able to use:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
```

I know it seems simple but this was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you still receive the same error after trying the other answers solutions try the following:

Go to the path where npm install packages globally.

- On **macOS or Linux** it's usually: /usr/local/lib/node_modules
- On **Windows**: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Search for create-react-app folder and delete it. You might need to delete create-react-app related files from parent folder:

- /usr/local/lib/
- C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\

You may also try the 'npm root -g' command to get the path, however, for me the returned path wasn't the correct one for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the cache with "npx clear-npx-cache", exit your code studio and relaunch it again. Then create your app. It works like charm. The studio code need to lose the session first and that is why we need to exit the ms-code first and relaunch.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me by clearing the npx cache

npx clear-npx-cache

Answer (score 0):

*I have resolved this issue with the following combination of commands* 

**1. First clear the cache**

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

**2. Now run this command, this will uninstall the old version, install the latest one and create a new app using npm**

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm
```

Comment: if it is same as an existing answer, you could have up voted it

Answer (score 0):

First update node to the latest version.download the package from website and reinstall it  .then update npm.then try `npx create-react-app@latest appname`.

Answer (score 0):

If you've previously installed `create-react-app` globally via `npm install -g create-react-app`, uninstall the package using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` or `yarn global remove create-react-app` to ensure that npx always uses the latest version.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

This solution working for me

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx clear-npx-cache
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Current as of 07/31/2023.
Install node js v.16 and everything will work

1. Install NVM
2. install node js v.16

nvm install 16

3. Select the current version (16)

nvm use 16

4. Building a React App

npx create-react-app my-app

Answer (score -1):

To clear a cache in npm, we need to run the `npm cache clean --force` command in our terminal:

```
npm cache clean --force
npx clear-npx-cache
```

*clean*: It deletes all data from your cache folder.

Answer (score -1):

**If you're using npm>5 and still getting this error. This might be you have installed old npm and then updated. Tried to clear the npm cache with the below command. It should work like charm.**

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Answer (score -1):

npx have cache, you can run `rm -rf ~/.npm/_npx` to clear cache

Comment: This answer offers no new information not present in currently existing answers