# "npm install -g create-react-app error" app give suggestions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I got this while installing create-react-app using  node. I think node package manager is not installed on my machine.

```
C:\Users\Jay>npm install -g create-react-app
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 8s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.

C:\Users\Jay>npx create-react-app testapp
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Jay
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-21T10_23_03_109Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Jay>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating new React app ("You are running \`create-react-app\` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-app-you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-w)