# I cannot update `create-react-app` despite globally uninstalling and using the standard 'npx create-react-app my-app' command

Tags: reactjs, npm, npx

I am trying to made a react app the standard way but hit the 'You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).' roadblock.

Despite doing the regular workaround that react recommends (global uninstall and use the new command), I still get the exact same error. I've looked at several solutions and nothing has worked. Where can I fix this for good?

Comment: use yarn instead of npm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating new React app ("You are running \`create-react-app\` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-app-you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-w)

Comment: As suggested By @Daniel use yarn to uninstall the CRA globally.

Comment: It does not recognize yarn as a command

Comment: @EricShingleton-Smith https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install/#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Answer (score 2):

Try `npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app`

Reference: [Error while creating new React app ("You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-app-you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-w/70358556#70358556)

Comment: I tried all the steps and even cleared the entire cache. I run into the exact same error.