# npm global uninstallition of old version of create-react-app not working

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

Today i was trying to create a new react application after a long break i took.
when i tried `npx create-react-app`, it gave me the following error:

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app
```

When I try to uninstall the old version of create-react-app using  `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

it shows the output:

```
up to date, audited 1 package in 432ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Then when i try to run `npx create-react-app` again, it shows the same error. can you please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while creating new React app ("You are running \`create-react-app\` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-app-you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `npx clear-npx-cache` before running `npx create-react-app` again.