# Not able to clear npx cache and install the new version of create-react-app i.e 5.0.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, nvm

I have the exact same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-app-you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-w). I have tried the following possible solutions

`npx clear-npx-cache`

output

```
Need to install the following packages:
  clear-npx-cache
Ok to proceed? (y) y
```

`npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

output

```
removed 67 packages, and audited 1 package in 380ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

`npm install -g create-react-app@5.0.0`
and it got installed successfully. After this when I tried `npx create-react-app frontend` it gave the same error that I was using 4.0.3 version of 'create-react-app'

this means that the npx cache is not cleared as it was supposed to.
It is worth mentioning that I am using nvm to manage my node version and am on Ubuntu 21.1
for this reason I checked out where my react scripts were

`npm ls -g create-react-app`

output

```
/home/vaibhav/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/lib
`-- (empty)
```

also I suppose the above command to clear npx cache actually deletes the `_npx` folder? I may be wrong here but the `_npx` folder is actually located in here

```
/home/vaibhav/.npm/npx
```

I just want to install the latest version of create-react-app scripts in the global directory hope the above information would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, so I ran
**npx clear-npx-cache**
it asked Need to install the following packages:
clear-npx-cache
Ok to proceed? (y) on clicking  **y** nothing happened so I ran

**C:\react>npm install clear-npx-cache -g**
It showed

added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 628ms

again Ran
**C:\react>npx clear-npx-cache**

and then

**C:\react>npm uninstall -g create-react-app**

it shows
up to date, audited 1 package in 278ms

at last, it let me install new version of cra after running **npm install -g create-react-app**
I also checked it ,by creating new react app ,
hope my answer, helps some one