# "You are running create-react-app 4.0.3 which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-install, yarnpkg, npx

I got an error while creating a React application. How do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the commands that it recommends? `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Comment: @BrandonDuffany Ya, I tried, But again shows the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-appyou-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-whi/70488154#70488154

Comment: when it prompts you to proceed, instead pressing enter, make sure to press 'y'

Answer (score 184, accepted):

It's fixed. I do `npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app`.

Reference: *[Error while creating new React app ("You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358474/error-while-creating-new-react-app-you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-w/70358556#70358556)*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do `npx clear-npx-cache` if you don't want to have to specify the cra version.

Comment: I could solve this problem using `npx create-react-app@latest my-app`

Comment: After clearing the cache for npm for almost 30 minutes to no avail. This worked for me. Sometimes you need to slow down and refocus. npx not npm

Answer (score 978):

Try running this:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I think this should be marked as the correct answer as it doesn't require forcing the latest version.

Comment: This worked for me too. This issue happened even after a fresh install of node js. This fix worked like a charm. <3

Comment: I think we need to add more detail on why this work

Comment: This is the correct answer I tried to find more details. 

Based on the response from James L here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510325/how-can-i-clear-the-central-cache-for-npx

create-react-app is still in npx cache memory even though it is not installed globally so clearing the npx cache using the command above solves it.

Comment: this fixed my issue also, no idea why this is crashing. but thanks

Comment: If you don't want to download `clear-npx-cache`, run `rm -rf ~/.npm/_npx` instead

Comment: This didn't work for me, running `npm update npx` and then `npx create-react-app my-app` worked

Comment: Got this! `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: I've been stuck on this problem for hours. Thank you so much! Upvoted.

Answer (score 75):

`npx clear-npx-cache` worked for me.

Try `npx clear-npx-cache` to clear your npx cache and then running the npx create-react-app your-app.

Additionally, it might be worth trying to force the latest version with:

```
npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm
```

Answer (score 47):

It's solved. By using this code:

```
npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app
```

If it does not work, use this and try again:

Delete everything from `C:\Users\your_pc_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-`cache

This could be a local caching issue. Try the command `npm cache clean --force` using administrator mode in your terminal and then try again with the same command - `npx create-react-app my-app`.

Answer (score 23):

**Follow this:**

> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

> npm cache clean --force”

> npm cache verify

> npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

this works--npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app

Comment: `npx clear-npx-cache` it worked for me as well