# Error using create-react-app. We no longer support global installation of Create React-App

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am  using the command `npx create-react-app React-app`, but it shows me the following error.

```
You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.1, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).
We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
```

I tried `npx create-react-app@5.0.1 React-app`, but it didnt work as well.

I have updated versions of npm and node.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create-react-app is not working since version 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963796/create-react-app-is-not-working-since-version-4-0-1)

Answer (score 2):

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

you can try this one and also check this post where you can find possible solutions : ["You are running create-react-app 4.0.3 which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358643/you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-which-is-behind-the-latest-release-5-0)

Comment: It doesnt work. Maybe you have another solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are using older global version of creat-react-app.
Please Kindly check the global version and update the version with below command

```
npm install -g create-react-app@5.0.1
```

or

```
npm install -g create-react-app@latest
```

**Note** : As you can see in the error there is no need to install **creat-react-app** globally so you can also uninstall the creat-react-app globally using below command

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Comment: It doesnt work. Maybe you have another solution?

Comment: npm uninstall -g create-react-app && npm i -g npm@latest && npm cache clean -f && npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm (run this command in your terminal)

Comment: The same error. I think the only solution is to reinstall Windows. Maybe i have some problems with system files.

Answer (score 0):

name of the project must be start whit lowwercase

Comment: True, but unrelated to the error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).