# install react in project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, installation

when trying to install react, it outputs an error:

*You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).*

*We no longer support global installation of Create React App.*

an attempt to reinstall node js on 16.15.0 or 18.1.0 failed. Also a solution from here ["You are running create-react-app 4.0.3 which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358643/you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-which-is-behind-the-latest-release-5-0) it didn't help.What is the reason for this?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Tried the two suggested answers here so far but still getting the same error. After I run 'npm uninstall -g create-react-app' it just returns `up to date, audited 1 package in 165ms` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1:clean your npm npx cache

solution 2 : `npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app`

Comment: I tried it didn't work

Comment: `npx create-react-app@5.0.0 my-app` threw an error, but in a fresh folder a `npx create-react-app@5.0.1 my-app` (latest version) did seem to work!

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using create-react-app as globle package.. you should try `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
and then try `npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: Returns `up to date, audited 1 package in 165ms` after I run `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and getting the same error.

Comment: This is not the solution to this answer he is getting errors by running this code. Please suggest alternate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by following steps:

1. search where create-react-app is: `$ whereis create-react-app`;
2. open the directory and delete create-react-app files;
3. install packages again: `npm install -g create-react-app`