# error with create-react-app, behind 5.0.1

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I ran

```
npx create-react-app my-app-name
```

it would throw this error:

```
You are running create-react-app
4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).
We no longer support global installation of Create React App.
Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["You are running create-react-app 4.0.3 which is behind the latest release (5.0.0)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70358643/you-are-running-create-react-app-4-0-3-which-is-behind-the-latest-release-5-0)

Answer (score 0):

If you simply run the command:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

and say yes to downloading the package, you can simply rerun the `create-react-app` command and it should work perfectly