# Why do I have the error after npx storybook latest with vue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, storybook

I'm havin an error while starting the node 18.18.0 vue3 storybook project,
npx storybook@latest init
C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules@storybook\cli\bin\index.js:23
throw error;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Alexander\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\pathe\dist\index.cjs'

While I did npm i at the start and upgraded node js to latet now.

Does anybody know why I'm having this error or what to do?

Comment: Considering that you have a problem in npx cache, you can start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510325/how-can-i-clear-the-central-cache-for-npx